# Values in multiline textbox to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a trouble here and I can't find solution anywhere or figure it out with the solutions I found.

I need to insert many values into a single multiline textbox and place it in multiple cells. I've tried many ways without success, so... The problem is this:

How do I change this:
[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdNUm.png)

Or this:
[Fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaYIQ.png)

Into this, using only a button on UserForm:
[Fig3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ywv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SPLIT` if you alwayse have space between numbers. 
 
Something like

```
Option explicit 

Sub test()

    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your sheet name")
    Temp = Split(UserForm1.TextBox1, " ")

    For i = LBound(Temp) To UBound(Temp)
        With ws
            'split returns array starting with 0 
            .Cells(i + 2, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00" 
            .Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = Temp(i)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```